# Unable to post via HTTP POST

Tags: android, http-post

i am trying to post data via HTTP Post using name value key pair. But I am unable to post . The post url is http://mastercp.openweb.co.za/api/dbg_dump.asp .Should I include some header also while posting? Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button ok;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but_signup_login);



        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                System.out.println("Clicked");
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://mastercp.openweb.co.za/api/dbg_dump.asp" });}});
    }






    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mastercp.openweb.co.za/api/dbg_dump.asp");

        System.out.println("Clicked again");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(34);
            String amount ="Ashish";
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Type", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Email", "ash@gmail.com"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Email_In", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Pass", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Mobile", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Mobile_In", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_ADSL", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Org", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_VAT", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Name", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Surname", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_RegNo", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Address", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Town", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Code", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_State", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_Country", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_ADSL", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_ADSL_Address", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Payment_CC_Alt", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Payment_Type", amount));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CProfile", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("COrder", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Debit_Name", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Debit_Bank", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Debit_Number", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Debit_Code", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Debit_Type", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TOS_Agree", amount));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Code", amount));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("package_activation", amount));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("session", amount)); 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OnceOff", amount));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit-button", amount));  


            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               System.out.println("Unsupported Exception "+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }  catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("  Exception last"+e);
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    } 




    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";
          for (String url : urls) {


             postData(); 
          }


        return response;
      }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}
}


}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so, please post the logcat output. (You should use `Log.e(LOG_TAG, message, e)` -- with some String values for `LOG_TAG` and `message` -- instead of calling `System.out.println`.)

Comment: "But I am unable to post" Why, what happens when you try? Is there an error? If so paste the log cat. If not please elaborate about what doesn't work with what you have so far.

Comment: Actually, I don't see where you are actually executing the POST.

Comment: @TedHopp I tried to execute in on clicking a button

Comment: shall I post the full code here?

Comment: You need to show where you are calling `httpclient.execute(...`, or whatever you are doing to actually make the POST. Just calling `httppost.setEntity` doesn't cause any network activity.

Comment: @TedHopp hi i just edited the full code above. can you please check it. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: @QuynhNguyen, I am not getting any error on logcat. Pleasse see the edited full code.

Comment: @FoamyGuy  I am not getting any error on logcat. Pleasse see the edited full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `postdata()` method doesn't actually *do* the post. You need to do something like:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicHttpContext());
```

Then you can process the response (starting by checking the value of `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`). For instance, if you're expecting string data in the response:

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String data = handler.handleResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: hi, even though i included 
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicHttpContext());

i am unable to post data. Could you please check were am I getting wrong..

Comment: @jihbvsdfu - Please indicate what's going wrong. Do you get an error message or exception of any kind? Can you verify (from the server logs) that the request never makes it to your server?

Comment: i am not getting any message on logcat.can you please figure it out..Thanks for your patience..if you dont mind can you please edit that code..

Comment: @jihbvsdfu - I don't see your latest code. How are you setting `response` in `doInBackground`? Perhaps the POST is executing but you are not reading the results? Can you check at the server end whether there is network activity?

Comment: Thanks a million for your help!!. The code is working now. The delay was due to some database issues..Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my personal checklist on implementing Restful requests:

1. Check for internet permission
2. Check if api actually works using Rest Client
3. Check if the URL is correct
4. Check if the port number is correct
5. Check for required headers

Answer (score 0):

This code has helped me a lot:

```
       /**
        * HTTP post request
        *
        * @param sUrl
        * @param ht
        * @return
        * @throws Exception
        */
        public static HttpData post(String sUrl, Hashtable<String, String> ht) throws Exception {
                String key;
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                Enumeration<String> keys = ht.keys();
                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                        key = keys.nextElement();
                        data.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
                        data.append("=");
                        data.append(URLEncoder.encode(ht.get(key), "UTF-8"));
                        data.append("&amp;");
                }
                return HttpRequest.post(sUrl, data.toString());
        }
```

Check full class here:

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?p=490